# python module has no attribute

Tags: python, attributeerror

AttributeError: module 'actions' has no attribute 'MoveEast' keeps popping up in the terminal. I've tried renaming the functions and doing different importing methods like

```
from actions import Actions
```

but nothing happens.

```
import items, enemies, dungeon, player, actions
#rooms.py
#function in question
def adjacent_moves(self):
    moves = []
    if dungeon.room_exists(self.x + 1, self.y):
        moves.append(actions.MoveEast())
    if dungeon.room_exists(self.x - 1, self.y):
        moves.append(actions.MoveWest())
    if dungeon.room_exists(self.x, self.y - 1):
        moves.append(actions.MoveNorth())
    if dungeon.room_exists(self.x, self.y + 1):
        moves.append(actions.MoveSouth())
    return moves

#actions.py
class Actions:
    def __init__(self, method, name, hotkey, **kwargs):
        self.method = method
        self.hotkey = hotkey
        self.name - name
        self.kwargs = kwargs

def MoveEast(Actions):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__(method=Player.move_right, name="Move Right", hotkey="r")

#from player.py
def move(self, dx, dy):
    self.location_x += dx
    self.location_y += dy
    print(dungeon.room_exists(self.location_x, self.location_y).intro_text())

def move_right(self):
    self.move(dx= 1, dy= 0)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change

```
def MoveEast(Actions):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__(method=Player.move_right, name="Move Right", hotkey="r")
```

to

```
class MoveEast(Actions):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__(method=Player.move_right, name="Move Right", hotkey="r")
```